# Is it considered good security to give your variables unhelpful names?

Tags: software-obfuscation

I was exploring my company's codebase yesterday and I noticed one class which had three variables named m_p1, m_p2, and m_p3. These variables are used very often in this class and each has a different, specialized type. (By "specialized," I mean something specific like "EmailSender" or "DateFormatter," not something generic like "int" or "std::vector").

I asked a coworker about this and he said this was a security feature: If our code fell into the wrong hands, it would be harder for a hacker to understand. Thus, our code is more secure.

My first response is that this does make our code harder to understand, but it's only a very minor inconvenience from a hacker's perspective and a minor, but constant, inconvenience for the developers working on the code. This behavior is actually only limited to two classes I could find, so it seems very half-heartedly implemented. I can work around the odd variable names and just try to memorize what corresponds to what, but I'm looking for others' perspective on this issue. Am I underestimating the security benefits or failing to think of something?

### EDIT:

Thanks to the comments, I've discovered this question is off-topic for this site. That lead me to look for where it would be on-topic, and I found [Security.StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com). Furthermore, I found [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29078/115809) which appears to be a near-duplicate of mine. The general consensus is that it does provide *some* security, but it should not be counted on and confusion to programmers should be considered.

I'm sorry to be off-topic.

Comment: Only if you're mainly afraid of what your future self could do to your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software development practices and has nothing to do with cryptography.

Comment: @EllaRose Sorry to be off-topic, could you suggest a more appropriate StackExchange?